# DocuSign hostname returned by GET /restapi/v2/login_information

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the rest API

```
 GET /restapi/v2/login_information
```

to get the login information. 
This API returns a baseUrl. For example:

```
{[\r][\n]"
  "loginAccounts": [[\r][\n]"
    {[\r][\n]"
      "name": "SomeCo",[\r][\n]"
      "accountId": "555555",[\r][\n]"
      "baseUrl": "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/555555",[\r][\n]"
      "isDefault": "true",[\r][\n]"
      "userName": "Marco Altieri",[\r][\n]"
      "userId": "6b011111-1111-1111-1111-bc65f9bec41e",[\r][\n]"
      "email": "maltieri@someco.com",[\r][\n]"
      "siteDescription": ""[\r][\n]"
    }[\r][\n]"
  ][\r][\n]"
}"
```

I am using the baseUrl https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/555555 for the next calls to DocuSign.

Unfortunately, the application servers for a client do not have direct access to the DocuSign servers.
I could have used an http proxy because the client API that I am using has this option, but there is not a proxy available to forward the requests from the internal network to DocuSign.

We have been able to solve this problem redirecting the traffic for example using iptables.

The application server is configured to call DocuSign using the url (for the dev server):

```
https://demo.docusign.net/
```

On the application server, the hostname demo.docusign.net is mapped in /etc/hosts with the IP address of the redirector box (the internal server).
This means that the application server sends requests to the redirector and this redirects the requests to the actual DocuSign server.
Everything works fine but I am wondering if:

1) there is a better way to do it

2) the redirector needs to be configured to forward the requests and to do so we need to know the IP address of the DocuSign server. This IP address is documented in an article published by DocuSign and so it seems ok to use it. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

For your second question: Yes, DocuSign publishes the IP addresses of our servers for both Demo and Production environments and it is fine to reference those IP addresses in your configuration. We also recommend adding these IP addresses to your white list to avoid any issues.

I'm not a networking expert but I'm confused why you can make the initial API call to login_information but then have issues to work around with subsequent calls. It's the same root